# Add attribute to tag only for certain users

Tags: java, thymeleaf

In a `Thymeleaf` view, I would like to add an attribute to a tag only if the current user is part of a certain role.

The produced html for users with `ROLE_USER` should be:

```
<paper-input readonly label="Mobile" value="[[info.user.gsm]]"></paper-input>
```

and for users with `ROLE_ADMIN` it should be:

```
<paper-input label="Mobile" value="[[info.user.gsm]]"></paper-input>
```

How could that be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of Thymeleaf's special handling of *boolean* attributes it is quite simple:

```html
<paper-input th:readonly="${#request.isUserInRole('USER')}" label="Mobile" value="[[info.user.gsm]]"></paper-input>
```

From the [docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#fixed-value-boolean-attributes) regarding fixed-value boolean attributes, where `readonly` is one of them:

> The Standard Dialect includes attributes that allow you to set these
>   attributes by evaluating a condition, so that if evaluated to true,
>   the attribute will be set to its fixed value, and if evaluated to
>   false, the attribute will not be set

Comment: This does not yield the expected result. The attribute must either be "readonly" or "readonly='readonly'" to be "true", or, to be "false", it must not be present at all, because "readonly='false'" is still truthy.

Comment: @yglodt Thymeleaf should handle this correctly, see update.

Comment: Yes, thank you, following the docs it works like this: <paper-input th:readonly="${#request.isUserInRole('USER')}" label="Mobile" value="[[info.user.gsm]]"></paper-input>

Comment: @yglodt you probably also want to use `${not #request.isUserInRole('ADMIN')}` because i think admin also has USER role